# how do i center an h1 on a page with a menu

Tags: html, css, menu, center

Im building a website with a menu, and as content for the home page, i have an
h1(id: titleh1), but it does not center.(i need the h1 to be centered horizontally) can anyone help me? This is my code:

> please run the snippet in full page, otherwise it does not work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/puntspam/css/style.css">
        <title>YebbuSpam Beta</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//webtinq.nl/puntspam/afbeeldingen/YebbuSpam.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="menu" style="float: left;">
        
        <button onClick="start()">krijg 30 punten</button><br>
        <button onClick="start1()">krijg 60 punten</button><br>
        <button onClick="start2()">krijg 90 punten</button><Br>
        <a href="https://webtinq.nl/yebbuspam/beta.html" download><button>Download YebbuSpam</button></a><br>
        <a id="url"  target="_blank" href="https://rewards.microsoft.com/"><button>Microsoft Rewards ➞</button></a><br>
        <a id="url" href="https://webtinq.nl/yebbuspam/index.html"><button>YebbuSpam Release ➞</button></a><br>
        
        </div>
        <button  id="menubutton" onClick="menu()">☰</button>
        <h1 id="titleh1">YEBBUSPAM BETA</h1>
        <script>
        document.getElementById('menu').style.display = "none";
        function menu(){
            if(document.getElementById('menu').style.display == "none"){
                document.getElementById('menu').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('menubutton').style.left = "200px";
            }else{
                document.getElementById('menu').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('menubutton').style.left = "0";
            }
        }
        
        function start(){
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            
            
            
        }
        function start1(){
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            
            
            
        }
        function start2(){
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            window.open("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000, "_blank");
            
            
            
        }
        
        

        </script>
        <style>
        body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            position: fixed;
        }
        
        #url{
            bottom: 0;
        }
        
        #menu{
            display: none;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #2c2d2e;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 98;
            position: absolute;
            
        }
        
        #titleh1{
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
            button{
                height: 50px;
                background:  #2c2d2e;
                border: 0px solid #1d1e1f;
                color: red;
                font-weight: bolder;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: grey;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                width: 200px;
            }
            
            #menubutton{
                width: 53px;
            }
            
            #menubutton{
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 99;
            }
            
            button:hover{
                color:  darkgrey;
                background: #1d1e1f;
            }
            
            #welcome{
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 0;
                left: 50px;
                height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried using text-align: center; on the h1, but it does not work.
Then i found out that i had to use margin: auto; but it does not work too.
Does anyone have a way to center the h1?
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Why do you want to position the h1 absolute? There is no need for it.

Comment: i tried using position absolute and margin auto to center the h1, but if theres no need for it, i will remove it from my code. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not centering because h1 width is not equal to container's width.Add `width:100vw` to h1

```
 <h1 id="titleh1" style="width: 100vw">YEBBUSPAM BETA</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```css
#titleh1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it does not work, still thanks!